# Trouble compiling c++ program on Mac OSX 10.9 with opencv

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, clang

I'm trying to compile a C++ program on Mac OSX 10.9 via the command line (and clang) that uses opencv (version 2.4.12) and am running into some problems.

I'm trying to compile the program by running the following in Terminal:

```
clang --std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ test.cpp -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12/lib -lopencv_core.2.4.12 -lopencv_ml.2.4.12 -lopencv_video.2.4.12 -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lc++
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::namedWindow(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
```

Along with a string of other opencv functions that can't be found.

Upon doing some additional research, I found out that the problem might be associated with using libc++ instead of libstdc++ as the library. I tried switching to libstdc++ and was stuck with the following error.

```
fatal error: 'array' file not found
#include <array>
```

I researched that error and found out that for the Mac, it was because of using libstdc++ instead of libc++. Essentially, I'm kind of stuck in a loop and need some help compiling this program. Any thoughts?

Comment: You probably need newer libstdc++. Or recompile opencv with libc++.

Comment: I had some trouble recompiling opencv with libc++. Would updating libstdc++ add in the old headers like array.h though?

Comment: you may try : http://tilomitra.com/opencv-on-mac-osx/ or http://blogs.wcode.org/2014/10/howto-install-build-and-use-opencv-macosx-10-10/

Comment: Would those be compiling opencv with libc++? I installed opencv via homebrew and it used libstdc++ by default.